# Squid 2.7.8 For Windows With SSL Enabled

Tags: windows, proxy, http-proxy, squid

I am looking for a squid 2.7.8 package with ssl enabled for windows. I tried to build my own but not able to built it. I tried on windows 7 and 10 both efforts was in vain.
If any can provide me the any squid 2.7 version with SSL configured that will be helpful
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. search for fresh download for windows on google
   [image: search for fresh win dl version]
2. after install remove defaults
   [image: remove defaults]
3. be sure squid install and run ok as win service
   [image: squid as win service]
4. config windows firewall, just inbound
   [image: config windows firewall]
5. allow all or trusted ips
   [image: allow all or trusted ips]
6. after reset squid service, test from client to connect it
   [image: connect as client]

I try it today and all connection types was passed successfully...